# Removing input box from the print preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to show an input box only on the print preview of the page and not on the main page.
I am using the following function to get the print preview:

```html
function fnPrint()
{
var prtContent = document.getElementById("colMain");
var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=2px,top=2px,right=2px;height=auto;toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');
WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
WinPrint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/common-media/styles/screen.css" />');
WinPrint.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/common-media/styles/privateBank.css" />');

WinPrint.document.close();
WinPrint.focus();
WinPrint.print();
WinPrint.close();
}
```

Can any body please tell how to show a input box called "Client Name" only on the print preview and not on the main page from where the print event is fired.

code for the input box on the main is as follow:

```html
<div id="clientname" >
                        <div class="formBlock bgInput120">
                           <label for="username">Client Name:</label>
                           <span class="input">
                           <input type="text" id="cname" name="cname" /></span>
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

Comment: i have used $("#clientname").css("display","none");...on the main page and $("#clientname").css("display","block"); in the fnPrint( ) function....in this way it is displaying Client name input box in both print preview and on the  main page too.

Comment: Why don't you just use a CSS media query?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a css media query:

```
@media print {
    #clientname{
        display:block;  /* show the Client Name when printing */
    }
}
@media screen {
    #clientname{
        display:none;  /* hide the Client Name normally */
    }
}
```

This checks what the current media is (print, screen, etc) and will only apply these styles when in the specified media.